# Bacpac vs dacpac for migrating database to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am deploying a large database (both schema and data) from an on-premise server to Azure SQL. I plan on using [sqlpackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh550080(vs.103).aspx) from the command line. It looks like there are two options:

1. Extract a DACPAC and then publish it to Azure, using the
   ExtractAllTableData option to include data in the extraction
2. Export a BACPAC and then import it to Azure

Is there a preferred option? I need this process to run in the fastest way possible, so I'd be curious if one option is better for performance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Grant said bacpac is dacpac+data.Below is one more definition that might help

"A bacpac includes the schema and data from the database. A dacpac containers only the schema and not the data"

You might have  understood, you need bacpac.

> I need this process to run in the fastest way possible, so I'd be curious if one option is better for performance.

We have few databases(400Gb) in Azure.we observed it is faster to import data when we load data from storage..The approach we followed was to load data into storage which is in same location as database and then import data..

SQLSERVER team tested a few options and they observed **BCP is fastest compared to remaining options**..

[image]

Below is how you import bcp data into azure

> bcp TestDB.dbo.Customer in "C:\Users\cesardl\BCP\Customer.txt"
>     -c -U mysqlazureuser@mysqlazureservername
>   -S  tcp:mysqlazureservername.database.windows.net
>   -P mypassword

**Further reading/References:**

[Importing/Exporting data to SQL Azure databases using BCP and SQL Scripts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2010/06/04/importingexporting-data-to-sql-azure-databases-using-bcp-and-sql-scripts/)
[Loading data to SQL Azure the fast way](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2010/07/30/loading-data-to-sql-azure-the-fast-way/)

Comment: Did you also test azcopy? I found that to be one of the fastest ways to get the file up to storage. All the rest is great information.

Comment: If this helps anyone else, I also found that it is important to target the correct Azure SQL service level when importing the database. Choosing Premium/PremiumRS reduced the import time significantly. Otherwise, you hit 100% DTUs and are throttled the entire time.

Comment: Good to know that,you also can downgrade  tier after import

Answer (score 6):

A DACPAC plus the data is a BACPAC. Personally, I'd use the BACPAC method.

Answer (score 4):

BACPAC with import: only work for empty or new databases

DACPAC + ExtractAllTableData with publish: you can have objects in the target database, and it will be overwritten by default